# Show Only Selected Rows jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has server side data, with 10 of thousands of rows.  I use jqGrids native `multiselect = true` , I then push/splice id's of selected rows on various jqgrid events...all of this works perfectly.  I would like to take this one step further and have a 'View Selected' option that the user can choose which will programmatically create a filter to only show rows that contain an id in my array of selected rows.

So if the user selected 125 rows of 10,000 when they choose the option 'View Selected' I would create a filter to only show those 125 rows that have an id in my array of selected rows.

Tried a few ways to show selected without filtering, by hiding rows but ran into the issue of user selecting a row on page 57...then they choose 'View Selected' and then the only way to see the selected was to navigate to page 57.

Tried toggling between `dataformat=json` and `dataformat=local` ... but this caused me some headaches with sType filtering way down in jqGrid code.

If anyone has a way to create this magical filter...or a better approach of filtering/sorting of selected server side data all help is appreciated.

I apologize for the ugly formatting we CRUD out the grid creation and we dont pretty print it =)

```
var selectedIDs = [], viewSelectedOnly = false;
    var WrapperDivID = $('#grid_wrapper'),
        GridDivID = $('#BatchBatchGrid');
    //used to help us get gridid out for shiftclick of header
    WrapperDivID.attr('data-id', '120');

    var _AppType = Enum.GridArray(Enums.Security_ApplicationType);

    $(document).ready(function () {
        GridDivID.jqGrid({


        colNames:[
            'LocationID' 
                ,
            'ChannelID' 
                ,
            'Post' 
                ,
            'Actions' 
                ,
            'ID' 
                ,
            'Posted' 
                ,
            'Channel' 
                ,
            'StoreCode' 
                ,
            'Location' 
                ,
            'Reference#' 
                ,
            'Remote Ref#' 
                ,
            'Open Date' 
                ,
            'Close Date' 
                ,
            'Sales + Tax' 
                ,
            'Status' 
                ,
            'Register #' 
        ],
        colModel:
        [
                {
name:
                            'Account_Location.ID'
                        ,
index:
                            'Account_Location.ID'
                        ,
width:
10                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
hidden:
true                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Channel_Channel.ID'
                        ,
index:
                            'Channel_Channel.ID'
                        ,
width:
10                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
hidden:
true                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Post'
                        ,
index:
                            'Post'
                        ,
width:
5                        ,
align:
                            'center'
                        ,
search:
false                        ,
sortable:
false                        ,
hidden:
true                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Action'
                        ,
index:
                            'Action'
                        ,
width:
10                        ,
align:
                            'center'
                        ,
search:
false                        ,
sortable:
false                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'ID'
                        ,
index:
                            'ID'
                        ,
width:
10                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
hidden:
true                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Posted'
                        ,
index:
                            'Batch_Batch.Posted'
                        ,
width:
10                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
search:
true                        ,
stype:
                            'select'
                        ,
searchoptions:
                            '{value: ddPosted }'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Channel_Channel.Name'
                        ,
index:
                            'Channel_Channel.Name'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Account_Location.StoreCode'
                        ,
index:
                            'Account_Location.StoreCode'
                        ,
width:
7                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Account_Location.Name'
                        ,
index:
                            'Account_Location.Name'
                        ,
width:
40                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'BatchNumber'
                        ,
index:
                            'Batch_Batch.BatchNumber'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'RemoteReferenceNumber'
                        ,
index:
                            'RemoteReferenceNumber'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'OpeningTime'
                        ,
index:
                            'OpeningTime'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'ClosingTime'
                        ,
index:
                            'ClosingTime'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
search:
                            'true'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'SalesPlusTax'
                        ,
index:
                            'SalesPlusTax'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'Status'
                        ,
index:
                            'Batch_Batch.Open'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                        ,
search:
true                        ,
stype:
                            'select'
                        ,
searchoptions:
                            '{value:ddStatuses}'
                }
                        ,
                {
name:
                            'RegisterNumber'
                        ,
index:
                            'RegisterNumber'
                        ,
width:
15                        ,
align:
                            'left'
                }

        ],

pager :$('#pager')                    ,
rowNum :"50"
                    ,
rowList :[10,20,50,100]                    ,
sortname :'Batch_Batch.Closingtime'
                    ,
sortorder :"desc"
                    ,
viewrecords :true                    ,
url :'../Grid/BatchBatchGetData'
                    ,
datatype :'json'
                    ,
mtype :'GET'
                    ,
autowidth :true                    ,
autoheight :true                    ,
height :400                    ,
multiselect :true                    ,
rownumbers :true        ,

        gridComplete: function(){
            var ids = GridDivID.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i ++){
                var id = ids[i];
                var link = '<a href="../Accounting/BatchView?BatchID=' + id + '" target="_new">View</a>';
                GridDivID.jqGrid('setRowData',id,{Action:link});
                if (viewSelectedOnly) {
                     if(selectedIDs.indexOf(id) === -1){
                        $('#' + id).css('display','none');
                     }

                 }
            }
            var curr_width = WrapperDivID.width();
            GridDivID.jqGrid('setGridWidth', curr_width);

        },
        onSelectRow: function(id, status){
            var p = this.p, item = $(this).getRowData(id), _index = selectedIDs.indexOf(id);
            if(status){
                if(selectedIDs.indexOf(id) === -1)
                    selectedIDs.push(id);
            }else{
                selectedIDs.splice(_index, 1);
            }
        },
        loadComplete: function(gridData){
            var p = this.p, data = p.data, item, grid = $(this), index = p._index, rowid, i, selCount;
            //Logic for view selected
            if (gridData.rows.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < gridData.rows.length; i++) {
                 if(selectedIDs.indexOf(gridData.rows[i].id) !== -1){
                    grid.jqGrid('setSelection', gridData.rows[i].id, true);
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        onSelectAll: function(aRowids,status){
            var p = this.p;
            for (var i = 0; i < aRowids.length; i++) {
                var  _index = selectedIDs.indexOf(aRowids[i])
                if(status){
                    if(selectedIDs.indexOf(aRowids[i]) === -1)
                        selectedIDs.push(aRowids[i]);
                }else{
                    selectedIDs.splice(aRowids[i], 1);
                }
            }

        }


        }); //Ends jqGrid instantiation


        GridDivID.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:true},{closeAfterAdd: true,closeAfterEdit: true},{closeAfterAdd: true,closeAfterEdit: true});
        GridDivID.jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter:true});
        //GridDivID.jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,minHeight:100});

    });  //Ends Document Ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for us, might not necessarily be easily implemented for others tho.
We have some server side code that takes the query string like this and parses it into a filter language that we use against SQL.

**Query String Parameters**

```
nd:1354661490131
rows:50
page:1
sidx:Batch_Batch.Closingtime
sord:desc
filters:{"groupOp":"OR","rules":[{"field":"Batch_Batch.ID","op":"in","data":"'fa8d00f6-3faf-47a5-a0b0-b21879f2e54f', '8a59b8a5-66de-4ad1-ac89-81e645303b8c'"}]}
```

I found this post by victorz
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/extendig-default-search-operators-list/
which gives all the potential jqGrid operators

**jqGrid Operators**

```
['equal','not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','contains','does not contain']

and correspndent list of aliases declared by sopt option:
['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','bn','in','ni','ew','en','cn','nc']
```

I didn't originally realize that there was a 'in' operator which is exactly what I needed =). In order to get it to work with the filter parser I had to change it from an array to a string...so `["1", "2" "3"]` to `"'1', '2', '3'"`

**How the Javascript to create filter looks**

```
    var grid = $('#BatchBatchGrid');  
    f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
// String that is used to store array values for server side filtering
    var arrayToString= '';
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedIDs.length; i++) {
    arrayToString+= (i != selectedIDs.length - 1) ? "'" + selectedIDs[i] + "', " : "'" + selectedIDs[i] + "'";
    }
    f.rules.push({ field: "Batch_Batch.ID", op: "in", data: arrayToString});
    grid[0].p.search = true;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true}]);
```

**Last Stop Filter builder - Server side**

When it hits controller side, the code gets scrubbed and eventually writes out some SQL syntax similar to 'where ID in ('1', '2', '3')'

Hope this helps others out there trying to accomplish this with server side data.  If anyone has any easier solutions I wouldn't mind seeing them, this one works well...but always like to see other methods =)